# FlowRouter redirect if user is logged in and if path is

Tags: meteor, flow-router

I'm using Meteor with FlowRouter and i'm looking for a condition like this:

- if the user is logged && if the accessed path is http://x.x.x.x/
- then redirect to http://x.x.x.x/clients

My current Routes:

```
    Accounts.onLogin(function(){
        FlowRouter.go('clients');
    });
    Accounts.onLogout(function(){
        FlowRouter.go('home')
    });

    FlowRouter.triggers.enter([function(context, redirect){
        if(!Meteor.userId()){
            FlowRouter.go('home')
        }
    }]);


    FlowRouter.route('/', {
        name: 'home',   
        action(){
            BlazeLayout.render('HomeLayout');
        }
    });
    FlowRouter.route('/clients',{
        name: 'clients',
        action(){
            BlazeLayout.render('MainLayout', {main: 'Clients'});
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(Meteor.userId() && FlowRouter.getRouteName() === 'route_name'){
    FlowRouter.go('/route_name');
}
```

In flow router docs there are a few was to get the current route if you need to restructure the statement above.
https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that you just have to change your FlowRouter.route('/'...) configuration a bit:

```
FlowRouter.route('/', {
  triggersEnter: [function(context, redirect) {
    if (Meteor.userId()) {
      redirect('/clients');
    }
  }],
  name: 'home',   
  action(){
    BlazeLayout.render('HomeLayout');
   }
 });
```

So any logged in user that accesses '/' will be redirected to 'clients' - worked fine when I tested it. Here's some background info in the flow router docs: https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router/blob/master/README.md#redirecting-with-triggers